# How do I pass an id to a link when using the method call syntax in a tagLib?

Tags: grails, taglib

I've got a tag definition:

```
def myCustomLink =  { attrs, body ->
    def url = complexUrl(attrs.whatever)
    def linkAttrs = [url: url, class:'css-class', id: 'actual-id']
    out << g.link(linkAttrs, body() ?: "Book a service")
}
```

I'd expect `id="actual-id"` in the HTML element to turn up in the output, but this isn't the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite confusing for beginners (sometimes) between `id` & `elementId` used in `g:link` Taglib.

The `id` attribute in various Taglibs like `g:form`, `g:link`, `g:textField` etc. is not for the `id` attribute of any HTML tag, instead this is the Identity or `id` field referencing a domain class. So if you use `id` in any of those taglibs, it's gonna be used in `/$controller/$action/$id` URL mapping (the default mapping).

So ultimately, to generate `<a>` tag with `id` attribute, you need to use `elementId` instead (as you already answered).

http://docs.grails.org/3.2.9/ref/Tags/link.html

> `elementId` (optional) - this value will be used to populate the id attribute of the generated href

```
Map linkAttrs = [url: url, class: 'css-class', elementId: 'actual-id']
```

Comment: Yeah, the documentation is a little confusing on this. I've submitted a pull request to hopefully clarify https://github.com/grails/grails-doc/pull/571

Comment: Wow great! Good job

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, (for anyone else who has this issue):

```
// Use the elementId attribute to pass an id for the anchor tag itself.
def linkAttrs = [url: url, class:'css-class', elementId: 'actual-id']
```

Found in the source code for ApplicationTagLib https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/72308377/

This is because the id attribute (and all other attributes) are used in the link href itself.